# Is it possible to use builtin deferred handler to schedule cron tasks in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I have the following in my app.yaml file

```
builtins:
- deferred: on

handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
  login: admin
```

It is possible to schedule some of the tasks exposed using google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application as cron jobs? What would the URL in cron.yaml file?

Comment: I have tried accessing a deferred function using a cron url but it didnt work, seems the cron is completely separate and has no access to the deferred library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

```
cron.yaml

cron:                                                                                                                                                                                    
- description: daily summary job                                                                                                                                                         
  url: /cron-job-url                                                                                                                                                                     
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

For example (not tested) In the request handler of `/cron-job-url` call the deferred task

```
class CronJob(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self): 
         deferred.defer(do_something_expensive, "Hello, world!", 42, True)
         self.response.set_status(200)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/cron-job-url', CronJob),
], debug=True)
```